# Handling Light box / Light window in selenium using webdriver

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver

I have been trying to automate a certain flow on a website, but whenever I navigate to the site a light box/window appears because of which my element is not getting selected.

I have tried 2 approaches to close the window but none of them are working:

1. Have tried to close the window using the pop up closing approach.
2. Have tried Frames approach but that isn't working as well.

Below is my code:

```
import java.util.Iterator;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Set;
import java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit;

import org.openqa.selenium.By;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebElement;
import org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.firefox.FirefoxDriver;


public class Handle_Windows_popUP {

    static WebDriver driver = null;

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub


        System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver", System.getProperty("user.dir")+"\\Drvier\\chromedriver.exe");
        driver = new ChromeDriver();
        driver.manage().window().maximize();
        driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(20, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
        driver.get("http://www.makemytrip.com");

        Set<String> id = driver.getWindowHandles();
        Iterator<String> itr = id.iterator();

        System.out.println(id.size());

        while(itr.hasNext())
        {
            Object element = itr.next();
            System.out.println("id: "+element);

        }

// Trying to find the 'X' button if present in any of the frame but none of the frame has it            

        List<WebElement> ls = driver.findElements(By.tagName("iframe"));
        System.out.println("Numberof frames:"+ls.size());

        for(int i=0;i<ls.size();i++)
        {
            driver.switchTo().frame(i);
            System.out.println("Frame: "+i);
            System.out.println(driver.findElements(By.xpath("*[@id='htmlDoc']/body/div[13]/div/a[1]")).size());
            driver.switchTo().defaultContent();
        }


// The Pop-up approach

        String parent_Window = itr.next();
        String child_win = null;

        while(itr.hasNext())
        {
            child_win = itr.next();
            driver.switchTo().window(child_win);
            driver.close();

        }

        driver.switchTo().window(parent_Window).getTitle();

    }

}
```

Comment: is this alert message or new window? can u share ur link?

Comment: The link to the website is www.makemytrip.com ( doesn't seems to be an alert .... pls help)

Comment: after launch, just refresh browser again like this:
driver.navigate.refresh();   let me know what happen. In my machine, if i just refresh the browser again, this popup disappear.

Comment: never forget to use wait.....thanks

Comment: Used driver.navigate().refresh(); and the pop up disappears.Although I was trying to close it by managing the pop up approach, is refreshing the browser is  the correct way of doing it ?....  Please help as I am new to Java (Selenium Web driver). And going forward is it advisable to use this approach ( the one of refreshing the browser) ?

Comment: as by refreshing browser is working, i think this is smart solution..... :), why u write some extra code...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

as this works fine if u refresh the browser, i will suggest u not to use any other code. But if u want to know how to close the window without refresh browser, write the below code after launch:

```
//wait until the browser loaded.
//than use this code
driver.findElement(By.cssSelector("div.appfest_container.appfest_container-bg.visible-md.visible-lg >a.appfest_container-close.pull-right.clearfix")).click();
```

my css path is long but u may change it by using xpath.

```
//*[@id="htmlDoc"]/body/div[13]/div/a[1]
```

and hope u will accept the answer.

Comment: have clicked it , but i need 15 reputation points , after that only it will be visible. ( i am new to stack-overflow).